# Scheme using and operator on reduce

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to use logical operations on `reduce`, for example:

```
(reduce and '(#t #t #t) 0)
```

This gives me an error, I'm not sure why.

```
(reduce + '(1 2 3) 0)
```

This works perfectly fine, but when I try to use the built-in `and` operation, it fails.
Can someone explain me why wouldn't this work? I am forced to use `reduce` on logical operation

Comment: `and` is not a function, as Terje D said, but you can make your own to pass around: `(foldl (lambda (x y) (and x y)) #t '(#t #t))` returns `#t` :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reduce` requires a function as its first argument, while `and` is a special form. Since special forms are not first class objects, they can not be used as arguments to functions (or be stored in variables).

An alternative to `reduce` in this case is

```
(every identity list-of-booleans)
```

while

```
(any identity list-of-booleans)
```

is a working alternative to `(reduce or ...)`

Comment: Are `every` and `any` standard Scheme functions/constructs?

Comment: @RSahu Almost. Like `reduce` they are specified in [SRFI-1 List library](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html)

Comment: @Terje D. I am required to use reduce function. I think I can work my way around since I know and is special form and not a operator. Making my own and would be easier I think.. Thank you very much